# return pdf instead of pdf url from laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pdf

I am using laravel. I don't want to return url of the pdf to the front-end, as it's located in google cloud and i don't want the link to be seen. That's why I need to return pdf directly and let user download it through browser.

I tried this:

```
return response()->json(['data' => file_get_contents(Storage::url($cert_path))]); 
//this says: malformed utf-8 characters, 500 error
```

Then I googled and tried this:

```
$file = file_get_contents(Storage::url($cert_path));
$file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
return response()->json(['data'=>$file]);
//this returns pdf, but in front, when i have a download code of js, when I download it, the whole pdf is empty.
```

The url of the pdf is correct, as I can go to that url and see the pdf.

how do I return pdf successfully?

I will also include javascript download code:

```
 var blob = new Blob([pdf], {
         type: 'application/pdf'
    });
   var link = document.createElement('a');
   link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   link.download = "ffa.pdf";
   link.click();
```

Comment: Just open a simple HTML link, return in your Controller the file with good headers to show the PDF in navigator.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Don't return `json`.

Comment: Gotchya. SO i will return response()->file but i also want to return some json too with that file. is it possible?

Comment: No, that won't be possible.

Comment: any idea what i should do then? I just need some json data and file to return to the front-end.